# Difference between errno and return code in Linux

Tags: c, linux

What is the difference between `errno` available from `<errno.h>` and the `return code` which can be printed using `echo $?` in bash. Are they referring to the same code?

Comment: They're not the same. https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno

Comment: Totally different.  System calls have return values, and if the return value is -1 indicating an error, `errno` gives the reason for the error.  `$?` gives a process's *exit status*, which is either the value the program returned from `main()`, or the value the program passed to `exit()`.

Comment: The return is the value of the actual `type` the function returns. In addition to to the return, certain functions (as described in the function man page) set a sequence of bits (an `int`) called `errno` (provided by `errno.h`) further describing why the function failed. For example see [man 2 open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) under the `"RETURN VALUE"` and `"ERRORS"` sections.

Answer (score 1):

A process's exit code doesn't usually correspond to an `errno` code.

The most portable strategy is just to have 1 for failure exits (or even more portably `EXIT_FAILURE` as defined in `stdlib.h`) and 0 for success exits.

Some programs follow the [bsd sysexits strategy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254747/23692) for mapping mores specific exit conditions to exit codes.

Other programs may choose to return `errno` codes (relevant to the system call failure that ultimately led to a process exit) or e.g., `errno+1` , and you'll usually be able to fit that into the 8 bits used by `exit`, but there's no system-wide-enforced exit code strategy or even an unenforced convention apart from a zero exit code meaning success and a nonzero exit code meaning (some kind of) failure.